# Delete the content of a txt file except the first line

Tags: powershell

I have two PowerShell scripts that:

- make a daily average number of backed up VMs and save it to a .txt file:

  ```
  $file = "E:\PS\Malik\valeurs.txt" 
  $success_rate = 100 - ($nbckp_vms * 100 / $total_vms)
  $success_rate_round = [Math]::Round($success_rate,2)

  #Exported into the $file path
  Add-Content -Path $file -Value "$success_rate_round,$total_vms,$nbckp_vms" 
  #        $text = Get-Content -path $file

  # Backup rate for production KPI

  $body = $body + "`r`n" + "*** Backup success rate for production KPIs ***" + "`r`n"

  $body = $body + "`r`n" + "Daily success rate = $success_rate_round%"
  $body = $body + "`r`n" + "Total VMs = $total_vms"
  $body = $body + "`r`n" + "Daily unbacked up VMs = $nbckp_vms" + "`r`n"
  ```
- make a monthly average number with the values of this .txt file.

And there's the problem. And the problem is with this part.

I wanted to make an upgrade about these two scripts that included the average number of VMs and the average number of non backed up VMs. So I did that:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path $path -Delimiter ','

$moy = $csv1.moy | measure -Average | select -expand average
$nb_total_vms = $csv1.nb_total_vms | measure -Average | select -expand average
$nbackedup_vms = $csv1.nbackedup_vms | measure -Average | select -expand average

Write-Host "moy = $moy / $nb_total_vms / $nbackedup_vms"
```

But since this script starts every months, I can't make my first line like "moy,nb_total_vms,nbackedup_vms" but instead I have the values and then this line. If I put it on my other script, I will have every lines this:

```
value
moy,nb_total_vms,nbackedup_vms
value
moy,nb_total_vms,nbackedup_vms
```

and so on.

I'd like to write this line (moy,nb_total_vms,nbackedup_vms) always on the first line of my .txt file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, the answer to your title:

```
(Get-Content "your.txt" -TotalCount 1) | Set-Content "your.txt"
```

Comment: More efficient would be `(Get-Content "your.txt" -TotalCount 1)|Set-Content "your.txt"` which wouldn't read in the *whole* file into memory first (as an array) and then unnecessarily split and only select the first one. Also AnsgarWiechers approach is superior.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `*-Content` cmdlets for writing your output files in the first place. Create custom objects and use `Export-Csv`. That will automatically produce the header line you want.

```
$prop = @{
    moy           = $csv1.moy |
                    Measure-Object -Average |
                    Select-Object -Expand Average
    nb_total_vms  = $csv1.nb_total_vms |
                    Measure-Object -Average |
                    Select-Object -Expand Average
    nbackedup_vms = $csv1.nbackedup_vms |
                    Measure-Object -Average |
                    Select-Object -Expand Average
}

New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $prop |
    Select-Object moy, nb_total_vms, nbackedup_vms |
    Export-Csv $file -NoType
```

The `Select-Object` in the above code (which works on all PowerShell versions) is just for ensuring the order of the columns in the output CSV. If you have PowerShell v3 or newer you can simplify it by using the `[PSCustomObject]` type accelerator, which automatically uses an ordered hashtable.

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    moy           = $csv1.moy |
                    Measure-Object -Average |
                    Select-Object -Expand Average
    nb_total_vms  = $csv1.nb_total_vms |
                    Measure-Object -Average |
                    Select-Object -Expand Average
    nbackedup_vms = $csv1.nbackedup_vms |
                    Measure-Object -Average |
                    Select-Object -Expand Average
} | Export-Csv $file -NoType
```